# Bezeichnung für eine Person, mit der man nur online zusammenarbeitet

Tags: single-word-request

Hintergrund meiner Frage ist die Arbeit in Open-Source-Projekten.

Was wäre ein passender Begriff für Menschen, mit denen man schon länger online zusammenarbeitet, die man aber nie persönlich kennengelernt hat?

Der Begriff *Freund* scheidet aus, weil das IMHO eine gewisse Zuneigung und – je nach Sprecher – persönliche Bekanntschaft voraussetzt.

Den Begriff *Bekannter* finde ich zu distanziert, das wäre für mich eher jemand, den ich mal getroffen habe und dessen Namen ich kenne, aber wenig mehr ... (Oder ist das nur meine Auffassung/Definition?)

Gibt es einen Begriff, der eine freundlich gesinnte, persönliche Beziehung zu einem Kollegen beschreibt? Etwas, das weniger stark als das Wort *Freund* ist, aber stärker als das Wort *Bekannter*?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Menschen, mit denen man zusammenarbeitet, werden i. Allg. als ***[Kollegen](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Kollege)*** bezeichnet. Dieser Begriff gilt auch für Menschen, die derselben Berufsgruppe angehören, ohne explizit zusammenzuarbeiten, z. B. Juristen, die sich gegenseitig als Kollegen ansprechen oder bezeichnen. Er gibt nur eine *fachliche* Verbindung an, ohne Rückschlüsse auf eine eventuelle *persönliche* Beziehung.

Für den Fall, dass die technische Art der Zusammenarbeit eine Rolle spielt, kann man entweder, wie schon vorgeschlagen, einen zusammengesetzten Begriff bilden *(Online-Kollege)* oder die Art des Projekts nennen (Kollege im verteilten Projekt XYZ). Ich habe auch schon den vielleicht irreführenden Begriff *virtueller Kollege* gehört, der ausdrücken soll, dass die Beteiligten nicht physisch in einem Büro zusammenarbeiten.

---

Edit nach Ergänzung der Frage:

Wenn der Grad der Vertrautheit zusätzlich ausgedrückt werden soll, helfen die guten alten Adjektive:

- ein guter Kollege (meist nicht primär auf die fachliche Leistung, sondern auf die Qualität der Zusammenarbeit bezogen)
- ein langjähriger Kollege (lange Zusammenarbeit bedingt oft Vertrautheit, und sei es nur aus Gewohnheit)
- ein lieber Kollege
- ...

Oder eben eine Umschreibung:

- ein Kollege, den ich sehr mag
- ein Kollege, mit dem ich gut zusammenarbeite
- ein Kollege, der mir wichtig ist
- ...

So weit ich weiß, gibt es im Deutschen keinen Begriff für eine Beziehung, die „mehr-als-Bekannter-aber-weniger-als-Freund“ ausdrückt.

Comment: Danke, habe meine Frage präzisiert.

Comment: @Jan , eigentlich gilt es hier als guter Ton, Fragen nicht so zu verändern, dass die vorhandenen Antworten danach "falsch" werden. Ich mach' nachher noch ein ergänzendes edit zum Thema "freundlich gesinnt".

Comment: Ich bin bei SE nicht neu und habe meine Frage mit voller Absicht nicht verändert, sondern ergänzt. Ich hätte sie vermutlich von vornherein ausführlicher ausformulieren müssen.

Answer (score 2):

Ein *Bekannter* ist jemand, mit dem ich bekannt bin. Meiner Meinung nach wäre jemand, den ich mal getroffen habe, aber nicht gut kenne, ein *flüchtig Bekannter*.

Entsprechend wäre das gesuchte Wort ein *Bekannter*, oder ein *Online-Bekannter*. Die Zusammenarbeit würde auch *Online-Kollege* nahe legen.

Comment: Danke, "Bekannter" ist aber eben nicht was ich suche: Wenn ich einige Jahre mit jemandem geschäftlich zu tun hatte kenne ich ihn besser als nur flüchtig. Vielleicht wäre "guter Bekannter" in diesem Fall geeignet.

Answer (score 1):

Wenn man insbesondere durch die Arbeit an einer gemeinsamen Sache miteinander verbunden ist, so kann man den Anderen auch als

> Mitstreiter

bezeichnen.